# How does a webserver recognize the landing page?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a pure HTML website cloned to my local XAMPP server, it is under 'foo' folder. In this folder, there are only .html files and an empty .htaccess file.
When I open URL localhost/foo, the browswer will open localhost/foo/index.html file. So the question is, how does the server know it was to open the index.html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the apache conf file for your XAMPP installation (*C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf*), you will find the following declaration under **DirectoryIndex**:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>
```

index.html ends up being the 6th file apache will try to load.  You can customize this list, restart apache in the XAMPP control panel and have a different default file load.

Answer (score 0):

This is determine by an Apache configuration `DirectoryIndex`. Example:

```
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
# The index.html.var file (a type-map) is used to deliver content-
# negotiated documents.  The MultiViews Option can be used for the
# same purpose, but it is much slower.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html.var
```

Answer (score 0):

The server will open index.html (or index.htm or index.php) when no other page is explicitly requested because that is the default page for every directory on a web site. If you ask for zyx.com\reports.html then you will open the reports.html page because you specified the page you want to view. When you don't ask for a specific page (i.e. you enter zyx.com in the address bar) the default page for that directory is the index page, so that is what opens. What happens if you type zyx.com and there is no index page created for that directory? The server will return a listing of all the files in that directory, displaying links to all documents and/or images. There will also be a link to the parent directory so, in practice, a viewer would be able to access your files to find things of interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mostly servers support index.html as default file. But if you have any other file which      you want to make it as landing page. You may change you htaccess

DirectoryIndex filename.extension

You can add multiple files there like following example. In this case anyone of theme present will be landing page. If all present then first will be given priority.

DirectoryIndex filename.extension filename.extension filename.extension
```